# undefined is returned using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am currently working with the redux toolkit I am facing an issue for the last 2 days.
The problem is when I am trying to select a state using the `useSelector` undefined is returned.

The code is given below:

reducer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const SchoolDataReducer = createSlice({
    name: "datasets",
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        getSchoolRecords(state, action) {
          
          return action.payload

        }
    }
})
export const { getSchoolRecords } = SchoolDataReducer.actions;
export default SchoolDataReducer.reducer;

export function getDataTriger() {
    return async function getSchoolDataThunk(dispatch, getstate) {
        try {

            const res = await axios.get("/getschool")

            dispatch(getSchoolRecords(res.data))

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import SchoolDataReducer from "./SchoolData"
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        School: SchoolDataReducer
    }
});
export default store;
```

result

```
const maindATA = useSelector(State => State.datasets)
console.log(maindATA); // undefined
```

Comment: You've a typo, the state is `state.School`, so instead of `const maindATA = useSelector(State => State.datasets)` it should be `const maindATA = useSelector(State => State.School)`. Voting to close as "
Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole state data structure is `{ School: [] }`, you can get the state slice using `useSelector(state => state.School)`.

Please see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#reducer about the data structure of the redux state. So you can change the `reducer` option of `configureStore` like below:

```js
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        datasets: SchoolDataReducer
    }
});

// In component:
const maindATA = useSelector(state => state.datasets)
```